# Execute Lynx from java app

Tags: java, linux, runtime, lynx

I want to develop a java application for my server, but I need to authenticate to a website API (Twitch). To do so, I need to connect to an account through a webpage, so I want to use Lynx to do so. However, when I try to start Lynx from my java application, the program hangs, and does nothing :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

        try{

            if (os.contains("win")) {

                // this doesn't support showing urls in the form of "page.html#nameLink"
                rt.exec( "rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);

            } else if (os.contains("mac")) {

                rt.exec( "open " + url);

            } else if (os.contains("nix") || os.contains("nux")) {

                // Build a command string which looks like "browser1 "url" || browser2 "url" ||..."
                StringBuffer cmd = new StringBuffer();
                    cmd.append( "lynx" + " \"" + url + "\" ");
                rt.exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", cmd.toString() });

            } else {
                return;
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            return;
        }
```

Apparently this is because Runtime.getRuntime().exec() may not work under certain conditions, but I couldn't find anything relevant to make Lynx work.

Server OS : Ubuntu server 14.10

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process`, you should read from it's stdout output and write to it's stdin (if the program expects it).

For specifics you can look at this article http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html section *Why Runtime.exec() hangs*.

BTW. The preferred way of executing processes right now in java is to use `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use java.net.URLConnection to make the request instead of starting an external process? That might be simpler, and it would certainly be more portable.